# How to extract data from parameters?

Tags: python, linux, bash, urlparse

I have over a thousand links which all have GET based parameters.

```
https://us.webuy.com/search/index.php/"><script>prompt(/XSS/)</script>
https://www.densuke.biz/help
http://www.ntrcars.co.uk/email.php?subject=%22%3E%3Csvg/onload=alert(/XSS/)%3E
http://www.americanexpress.com/thailand/en/leave_country.shtml?url=javascript:alert`XSS`
https://share.trin.cam.ac.uk/sites/public/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?FollowSite=0&SiteName='-confirm(/XSS/)-'
http://www.rockwellautomation.com/global/news/the-journal/detail.page?docid=dfb8c8ba15e7cf2c599fc321b8e2b98e&G11N/Locale=en&geography=%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=x%20onerror=prompt%28/XSS/%29%3E&content_type=magazine&pagetitle=\n
https://www.ifishillinois.org/profiles/display_lake.php?waternum=1/*-/*`/*\`/*'/*"/**/--></script><svg/onload=;prompt(/XSS/);>00116
http://tools.xaa.su/htaccess/
http://www.wa.lk/realstate/product_display.php?id=%22%22;%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Eprompt(%2FXSS%2F)%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C%22
```

I need to extract all of the data which contains the string 'XSS' and put them into a list.

```
"><script>prompt(/XSS/)</script>
%22%3E%3Csvg/onload=alert(/XSS/)%3E
javascript:alert`XSS`
'-confirm(/XSS/)-'
```

and so on...

I have attempted to use urlparse but don't see this type of function anywhere

```
#from urllib.parse import urlparse
#
#url = 'http://user:pwd@NetLoc:80/path;param?query=arg#frag'
#parsed = urlparse(url)
#print('scheme  :', parsed.scheme)
#print('netloc  :', parsed.netloc)
#print('path    :', parsed.path)
#print('params  :', parsed.params)
#print('query   :', parsed.query)
#print('fragment:', parsed.fragment)
#print('username:', parsed.username)
#print('password:', parsed.password)
#print('hostname:', parsed.hostname)
#print('port    :', parsed.port)
```

To be clear; each URL will have a javascript payload that I'm looking to extract.

Answer (score 2):

For almost all the urls you posted (with exception the first one) you can extract `js-payload` from parsing `query` parameter like so:

```
import urlparse

# file.txt contains the urls - one per line
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().splitlines()

for url in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if parsed.query != '':
        print parsed.query
```

For the first one, the payload is contained in the `path` parameter.

Another way to extract get parameters is the following, using [`furl`](https://github.com/gruns/furl) module:

```
from furl import furl
for url in urls:
    i = furl(url)
    if len(i.args):
        for k,v in i.args.items():
            print v
```

**Update**
If all your payloads contain the word 'xss' then the following may help:

```
import urlparse

# file.txt contains the urls - one per line
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().splitlines()

for url in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if parsed.query != '':
        print ''.join(filter(lambda i: 'xss' in i.lower() ,parsed.query.split('=')))
```

**Output:**

```
alert(/XSS/)%3E
javascript:alert`XSS`
'-confirm(/XSS/)-'
prompt%28/XSS/%29%3E&content_type
;prompt(/XSS/);>00116
%22%22;%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Eprompt(%2FXSS%2F)%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C%22
```

Comment: I don't want to include the actual parameter, only the data / payloads.

Comment: @fedsikan What you are asking is not easy to implement since some of the payloads are obfuscated - anyway I updated the answer with one more try. Maybe you need to write a more detailed and complicated script with more advanced `regex` patterns to fully accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: why can we not just strip the data passed "="? The payloads are not obfuscated, they are simply URL encoded.

Comment: @fedsikan of course you can `split('=')` but then you'll get all parameters even those that are not js-payloads - so how will you detect if it's a js-payload. Also it may would be better to ask this question on [information security stack exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @fedsikan ok, so i could split(), what if we placed the data from each parameter on a newline and simply grepped for those lines which contain the unique value XSS'?

Comment: well yes, if you are only interested in payloads that contain the "xss" word then it would be easy to filter out those values.

Comment: is there a way to put each parameter on a newline? thanks for your extended assistance

Comment: @fedsikan what do you mean? - they are printed in lines already!

Comment: so each literal parameter is on a new line.

Comment: searched=Y&log=1&skey=all&hid_pr_text=&hid_link_url=&edit=&sword=scrub%22%20autofocus%20onfocus=confirm(/OPENBUGBOUNTY/)%3E&x=0&y=0 becomes:

Comment: @fedsikan That's trivial: `print 'searched=Y&log=1&skey=all&hid_pr_text=&hid_link_url=&edit=&sword=scrub%22%20autofocus%20onfocus=confirm(/OPENBUGBOUNTY/)%3E&x=0&y=0'.replace('&','&\n')`